# Trying to implement an action listener for a Card Game

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to get an image(a card image) for my game to appear blank when its clicked on. I want it to appear a blank image to simulate it disappearing. It's for a tri peaks solitaire game. I already have a function which tests if the card is valid to play or not, I'm just having trouble getting this to work properly, being new to Javascript. Or if anyone knows a better way I could go about this, I'm all ears, thanks.

This is a portion of the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

 <button onclick="newGame(); Deal();" style=" top: 35px; left: 80px; position: absolute;">New Game

 <div onmousedown="A(this)"><button onclick="Tri_Peak_Game()"><img id="leftRow4E1" src="cardback.jpg" alt="cardback" style="width: 100px; height: 150px; top: 200px; left: 150px; position: absolute;" /> </button> </div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">







</script>
</html>
```

Comment: does `blank_dissapear.png` exist? (including the misspelling?)

Comment: I'm sorry but using the code in your question there is no possible way to reproduce the error. Please [edit] your question in include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple proof of concept implementation that uses [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to handle `mousedown` and `mouseup` events on "card".

```js
function cardMouseDown(event) {
  event.target.src = "http://www.alderac.com/images/2015/01/playing-cards.jpg";
}

function cardMouseUp(event) {
  event.target.src = "http://globe-views.com/dcim/dreams/card/card-04.jpg";
}


document.querySelector('.card').addEventListener('mousedown', cardMouseDown);
document.querySelector('.card').addEventListener('mouseup', cardMouseUp);
```

```html
<div>
        <img class="card"
             id="leftRow4E1"
             src="http://globe-views.com/dcim/dreams/card/card-04.jpg"
             alt="cardback"
             style="width: 100px;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe this will help me implement what I need to occur in my program.